# Update table with another table values (several columns) in R

Tags: r, join

I am trying in R to update a table A with another table B only when values in table B are not NA. For example, if table A is:

[image: Table A]

and table B is:

[image: Table B]

I would like to have, as a result:

[image]

Would anyone the best way to do that?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
A <- tribble(
  ~ name, ~X1, ~X2, ~X3,
  "AX", 1, 1, NA,
  "BL", 6, 1, 3,
  "CD",NA, 4, 6,
  "DA", 4, NA, NA)

B <- tribble(
  ~ name, ~X1, ~X2, ~X3,
  "AX", 4, 5, 6,
  "BL", NA, 3, 4,
  "DA", NA, 4, 6)

bind_rows(A, B) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(!is.na(last(.)), last(.), first(.))))

  name     X1    X2    X3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 AX        4     5     6
2 BL        6     3     4
3 CD       NA     4     6
4 DA        4     4     6
```